# How to change Record on client directly, without transaction

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a very common situation, if there is a term for it, well I am not aware of it then.

A record is having **fields:** id, enabled, text, etc...
and having POST /record/enable to enable or disable record, as it invoke is bigger process on server.

So, once callback from normal POST is received, I want to update record.enabled to true locally, which should not be part of any transaction. and should be updated directly.

How to achieve this?? Or what is better alternative for such requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I think something along these lines should do:

```
App.PObject = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('number'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),

    nestedObject: function() {
        if (!this.nestedObj) {
            this.nestedObj = Ember.Object.create({
                active: false
            });
        }
        return this.nestedObj
    }.property()

});
```

As i have seen so far, Model is dirty only when its attributes, that are defined as `DS.attr`, change.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** Realized later that, This solution doesn't work.

Proper term of my problem is: transient field
Transient field of an Object is ignored for serialization/deserialization (like Java ORMs ignores transient fields) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_(computer_programming

I have figured out a solution. Its really simple.

```
App.PObject = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('number'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    //will not be part of Ember-data persistence, but will be populated on GET
    enabled: null
});
```

Object (Record) properties which are not attributes are ignored.